# Java Spring and Hibernate development environment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Someone told me to learn Web devolpment in Java. So I come across Java Spring. But After exploring I came to know about "Spring and Hibernate development environment"  And I am still confuse what is basic diff in it. And are there other frameworks of java etc ? In which wey do Spring MVC ? I am Php and python guy And New in Spring so kindly don't mind if I am wrong in asking question.

Comment: what exactly is your question here?

Comment: You primary need a proper IDE do develop with. Eclipse and IntelliJ are proper choices. But what is your main question?

Comment: This might be a small snack for you broader question - Still I would try my best...
Spring and Hibernate a large open source and the contributors are large in number and most of the solution are already into the box. I Hope you are not familiar with Java frameworks since I could understand from your question - Mean a part time development in Java Framework.

Comment: @SASIKUMARS yes I mentioned I am new in java. can you clear then I can Say Spring MVC vs Spring Hibernate ? I have to use 1 at a time ?

Comment: OK.. "Spring MVC" stands strong in middle layer of application as it manipulates data and renders data back to the user. "Spring Hibernate" used to connect to different databases with applications using annotations(current approach) which are more powerful and abstract.

Comment: @SASIKUMARS can you post it as question ? I will accept it. And last point which I understand is that, Hibernate we use to switch between diff databases ?

Comment: Post it as question or as answer? 
You can switch between databases but the configuration changes is only required, if you are not using any native query from your application to query database.

Answer (score 0):

- Hibernate provides a lot of feasibility while dealing with the database.
- It provides with ORM where in you are able to perform database transaction is the form of objects mapped to corresponding table, using configuration xml files.
- Spring, on the other hand is a framework that helps you follow the MVC architecture in an effective and efficient way. 
  It simplifies writing back end code as well as front end stuff providing clear demarcation simultaneously.

Comment: then I can Say  Spring MVC vs Spring Hibernate ? I have to use 1 at a time ?

Comment: You should start to learn Spring MVC, It is like another PHP MVC Framework in definition at least. Start learning from a point and you will come across many new thing and will know the difference on your on.

Comment: Actually I am about to buy course on UDEMY  https://www.udemy.com/spring-hibernate-tutorial/. In which he will teach Spring hibernate . But In description he mentioned that Spring MVC aswell. I am confuse there.

Comment: for a better experience in some cases, you can migrate hiberntae to spring Data (which is based on Hibernate framework) and take even less time to config it properly. However, there are some issues - in some situation its so hard to write tests for hibernate...

Comment: @F128115 Let me clear up this. Spring MVC is a pattern which is called Controller-Model-View. A classical application achitecture, which is quite common in java development. Speaking of Hibernate, hibernate is an ORM framework, that allows to work with databases and in most situations to assist with serialization/deserialization process(save/get data from database). In MVC pattern, hibernate is "Model'' that helps to save/read data form database. Take a closer look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: @Reborn thank you brother. I got what you want from your answer . Thank you again.